# Relatively positioned divs will not completely separate

Tags: css

[image: Force two relatively positioned divs apart]

It hope that it's clear from my sketch that #shell and .container are both relatively positioned divs.  I want them to stay relative because I'm trying to keep everything resizeable for responsive design.

There are other elements within the two relatively positioned divs, and one of those, the full-page image, is absolutely positioned so that I can place stuff on top of it.  It's coded inside the #shell div.

The problem is that even though #shell and .container are relatively positioned, they will not fully separate unless I force them apart with margins.  This is disappointing because I've always thought that relative positioning (display:block) is automatically on a new line and does not overlap a preceding div.

I have not bothered to add my code to this because it's now all over the map with everything that I've tried (floats, display options, z-indexing, et cetera). Yes, a top-margin, for example added to .container will separate the divs, but the effect of margins is not consistent for varied screen widths, not even when margins are expressed as percentages. And besides, adding margins and media queries does seem like a flaky way to accomplish something that is likely much simpler.

I'm interested to hear from someone who can show me how to force those two cantankerous bastards apart.

Comment: Could we've the code pls?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if I change ...

div class="container"

to ...

div id="container"

...it suddenly all works as it should.  This is another mystery for me, at least according to my understanding over the years regarding the distinction between id and class.

I've made the change, and that is what I'll stay with.

Comment: This proved to be a misconception.  So to further illustrate the problem, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j4ea2uwh/